# Is there a way to deploy a Heroku server on a Vercel front end?

Tags: heroku, vercel, react-fullstack

I have a server that I'd like to deploy on Heroku and a client-side app that I deployed on Vercel. Is there a way to change the domain of the server that heroku hosts on from `example.herokuapp.com` to `example.vercel.app/api`? It would be a lot more convenient if both were at the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can change the domain for heroku app but it has to be one that you maintain/own (e.g., through a DNS hosting service). You can't change it to something else like example.vercel.app since that's owned by Vercel.

Comment: If you're asking about a way to have Vercel and Heroku talk, well that's a separate post.

Comment: No, that's fine, I'm just wondering if I could host them on the same domain. Thanks anyways.